# Реализация метода Dispose() в классе, инкапсулирующем логику работы с контекстом данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, autofac

Есть WebApi2 с CRUD-функциональностью (добавление, обновление, изменение, удаление записей) для одной единственной таблицы Books. Для доступа к данным используется EntityFramework, в Global.asax устанавливается инициализатор БД:

```
protected void Application_Start()  
{ 
        AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer();

        Database.SetInitializer(new BookDbInitializer());
        ...
}
```

Контекст данных:

```
public class BookContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books
    { get; set; }
}
```

Есть класс Repository, который инкапсулирует логику работы с этим контекстом данных. И вроде бы поскольку в Repository используется неуправляемый ресурс (подключение к базе данных) нужно реализовать интерфейс IDisposable :

```
public class BookRepository : IRepository, IDisposable
{
    public BookContext Context
    { get; set; }
     ...

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
                Context = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Для внедрения зависимостей используется Autofac.

Контроллер общается только с Repository

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    public IRepository Repository
    { get; set; }

    public BooksController(IRepository r)
    {
        Repository = r;
    }

    // GET: api/books
    public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks([FromUri]BookFilterParams filterParams)
    {
        var books = Repository.GetBooks();

        // Фильтруем по автору
        books = Repository.FilterByAuthor(filterParams.Author, books);

        // Фильтруем по жанру
        books = Repository.FilterByGenre(filterParams.Genre, books);

        // Фильтруем по году выпуска
        books = Repository.FilterByIssuedDate(filterParams.MinIssuedDate, filterParams.MaxIssuedDate, books);

        return books;
    }
    ...
}
```

Проблема в том, что при такой реализации метода Dispose() в классе BookRepository, в API можно сделать ровно один запрос, на втором запросе всё ломается: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.' То есть действительно вызывается метод и уничтожает контекст данных. При этом, если в методе Dispose() закомментировать обе строки (то есть фактически не реализовывать его), запросов в API можно делать много и всё отлично работает! Вот только неуправляемый ресурс подключения к базе данных не освобождается тогда :(

Comment: а вы его как синглтон в autofac зарегистрировали что ли? Репозиторий (и контекст) должен пересоздаваться на каждый запрос к web api

Comment: В Autofac репозиторий с контекстом так регистрируется:  `builder.RegisterType<BookRepository>().As<IRepository>().WithProperty("Context", new BookContext());`

Comment: `builder.RegisterType<BookRepository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerRequest().WithProperty("Context", new BookContext());`    -- так вроде бы репозиторий с контекстом должен создаваться на каждый запрос, но ошибка остается

Comment: Вы создаете контекст прямо при регистрации один раз, а надо создавать на каждый запрос

Comment: @tym32167, но регистрация типа с указанием `InstancePerRequest()` -- так разве не будет создаваться новый экземпляр класса для каждого запроса?

Comment: новый экземпяр репозитория - да. Новый экземпляр контекста - нет.

Comment: @tym32167, извините, но разве указывая `WithProperty("Context", new BookContext())`  свойство `Context` не будет инициализироваться новым экземпляром контекста `BookContext`?

Comment: Нет, вы же контекст прямо в этом коде сами создаете (`new BookContext()`)  , он и будет переиспользоваться каждый раз. Вам надо как то по другому эту зависимость зарегистрировать. Как именно - я не помню, давно с autofac не работал